# Gray-scale operation on nodes

Tags: node-editor

While I was  playing with nodes I wanted to check which gray-scale algorithm blender use. And i came up with this node system: 
[image] 
But I got this strange result. Where did i make mistake?

Comment: Why is this a strange result? What would be the correct output?

Comment: Are you expecting the left half to be grey as well? If so, add the outputs from the _Multiply_ nodes together (you'll need two _Math_ nodes set to _Add_), rather than recombining them. With the setup you have now, you're just remapping the input colours to somewhat different out put colours.

Comment: Wow, @DuaneDibbley, you are actually right! Thank you! I wish I  could mark your message as answer!

Comment: I think you should accept @troy_s's answer, because it tells you the same thing as my comment, and adds a little to it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The luminance weights are intended to be summed. That is, for any given colourspace, multiply each light by its luminance position, and sum the result with the other two. You will end up with equal values across all three channels.

For REC.709 lights, which are the lights that define the sRGB specification, the formula would be:

Y = 0.2126*R + 0.7152*G + 0.0722*B